# naïve Bayes classifier

Tags: matlab

I am working on a naïve Bayes classifier and would like to classify some data using MATLAB. In the example of Fisher's Iris Data as given in MATLAB ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/classification.html) for details), they consider only the first 2 variables (Sepal Length & Width). I would like to proceed with classification with more features such as Petal Length and Petal Width.

In the documentation of this Fisher Iris example it is mentioned that "You can use the two columns containing sepal measurements." I want to take 3 or 4 columns means 4 properties with 2 classes. I want to plot the classes on x-axis and y-axis. How I can do this?

Comment: If you have four input dimensions (sepal length/width, petal length/width), you can not plot the classes in two dimensions - you would need four dimensions. Have you tried calling `fitcnb` with all inputs, instead of only the sepal width/length?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot things in 3D, and use color as your fourth dimension. However this will not be readable at all especially with large datasets.

I recommend you plot combinations of 2D because you will need to use color encoding for your class type normally.

The MATLAB machine learning app can be very helpful to you.